# Remove devices from provisioning profile with Fastlane

Tags: ios, fastlane

I'm using `match` and `register_devices` to get the right devices in my profiles.

When I remove devices via Apple Developer Fastlane tells me it can't find my provisioning profile anymore. So I have to nuke everything and create it again via Fastlane.

Is there a better way? Something like `register_devices` that throws out missing devices from the provisioning profile, when I deleted them from the call or something?

Answer (score 1):

Any time you delete a device, provisioning profiles with that device become invalid.

If you want to do this programmatically, you can use `disable!` on the device object to disable a device, e.g.:

```
device = Device.find_by_udid "abcde-12345"
device.disable!
```

But just like when you do it via the dev portal, it will invalidate all provisioning profiles that use this device.

I find it easier to keep a list of devices in source control and then use `match` and `register_devices`. Just set it up so it happens automatically instead of doing it by hand and it won't be a big pain.

Comment: I do it with `match` and `register_devices` but when I remove one from the list in `register_devices` it will still end up in my provisioning profile. When I change the profile on the dev portal, fastlane tells me that it can't find the profile anymore.